# How to disable part of an animation

Tags: animation, keyframes, drivers

I have a complex animation with lots of thing like position, colors, etc animated using keys and drivers. I'd like to disable some of the aspects without removing anything.

For example, here the rotations are animated. How could the rotation about the x-axis be disabled then re-enabled?
[image]

What is the best way to non-destructively disable a key and driver?

Comment: You can use a *Limit* modifier to block (mute) the animation for a given time, which will cause a moving object to stop and then teleport to where it would have been if it didn't stop. If you don't want the teleport and want to delay an animation, you could parent the object to another, with all animations scaled by `-1` along `Y:0`.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is probably to check the "Do channels contribute to result" checkbox. This toggle can be found in the title section of any available channel, immediately to the left of the padlock icons. This feature is available from both the Dope Sheet as well as the Graph Editor.